# Create virtual Printer where each tray is its own printer

Tags: windows, printing, printer, network-printer

I have a piece of software that prints many types of reports automatically including labels, A4 Notes, etc. Before clicking print I have to select the correct printer. If I choose the wrong one it crashes the software.

This has meant that I have needed 5 different printers to be able to print everything I need.

The software does allow me to specify a different printer tray per report:

[image: Image of Printer Settings]

On Windows 10, is it possible to set up a virtual printer, where each tray forwards the job to other printers? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way to simplify this.

First create as many duplicate printers as you need. Then, go to Printer Properties and click the Advanced tab. Click the Printing Defaults button and make your tray settings. Click OK.

Next, click on Printing Preferences and make sure the settings you changed are showing there. Correct if necessary.

Finally, while in Preferences, change the name of the printer to something that tells you which tray it will use.